# unauthorized access exception while using accelerometer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i'm trying to navigate between pages every time the user shakes the windows phone device but every time i'm changing the axis , an unauthorized access exception is shown

```
    public Welcome_2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
            Accelerometer acc = new Accelerometer();
            acc.TimeBetweenUpdates = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5);
            acc.CurrentValueChanged += new EventHandler<SensorReadingEventArgs<AccelerometerReading>>(accEventHandler);
            acc.Start();
    }
    private void accEventHandler(object sender, SensorReadingEventArgs<AccelerometerReading> e)
    {
        Vector3 accelReading = new Vector3();
        accelReading.X = (float)e.SensorReading.Acceleration.X;
        accelReading.Y = (float)e.SensorReading.Acceleration.Y;
        accelReading.Z = (float)e.SensorReading.Acceleration.Z;
        if (accelReading.X > 0 || accelReading.X < 0)
        {

                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Get_Insert.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make use of sensors(accelerometer), add Microsoft.Devices.Sensors and Microsoft.Xna.Framework references to your project. 
**Also make sure that ID_CAP_SENSORS capability is checked in capabilities of App manifest file which is under Properties folder of your project.**

Comment: thanks for your response 
but i have found the error in my code 
i can't write directly on the accelerometer event handler but i must call another method to write my code in through 'Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MethodName());